# Using Scrapy with Selenium to scape a rendered page

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I fixed all the issues, the only problem is I am getting a permission error because I cannot figure out exactly how to connect Firefox to this script, I've installed the plugins and I can make it work from the UI but not this script.

How do I do this?

Here is my code...

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from selenium import selenium

from linkedpy.items import LinkedPyItem

class LinkedPySpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'LinkedPy'
    allowed_domains = ['linkedin.com']
    login_page = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
    start_urls = ["http://www.linkedin.com/csearch/results?type=companies&keywords=&pplSearchOrigin=GLHD&pageKey=member-home&search=Search#facets=pplSearchOrigin%3DFCTD%26keywords%3D%26search%3DSubmit%26facet_CS%3DC%26facet_I%3D80%26openFacets%3DJO%252CN%252CCS%252CNFR%252CF%252CCCR%252CI"]

    def __init__(self):
        InitSpider.__init__(self)
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.linkedin.com")
        self.log("\n\n\n Starting the Selenium Server! \n\n\n")
        self.selenium.start()
        self.log("\n\n\n Successfully, Started the Selenium Server! \n\n\n")

    def __del__(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        print self.verificationErrors
        CrawlSpider.__del__(self)

    def init_request(self):
        #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        #"""Generate a login request."""
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'session_key': 'email@address.com', 'session_password': 'password'},
                    callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
        if "Sign Out" in response.body:
            self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
            # Now the crawling can begin..
            return self.initialized()
        else:
            self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")
            # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)        
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open(response.url)
        time.sleep(2.5)
        sites = sel.select('//ol[@id=\'result-set\']/li')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = LinkedPyItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('h2/a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = site.select('h2/a/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: The Connection Refused happens because I did not have the Chrome server running... Yet it stuck after `Enabled item pipelines:` not doing anything? Any Ideas?