# Scrapy can't see passed login page even after selenium is sucessfully authenticated

Tags: authentication, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and subsequently Python and as a result have been heavily relying on searching through other peoples questions to get this far, however I haven't been able to find any that helps me with this problem.

The script I'm working on first has to log into an asp page that heavily uses JS. This took me a while to wrap my head around but I finally got passed it by using selenium. When I run the script it pulls up the browser, logs in, and successfully displays the page I want. However when I try to scrape data it returns results from the original login page. I have also run through it in the Scrapy shell to the same effect and I'm not really sure what the root of this issue is. So to keep it simple I've been selecting the title and when it should return the title of the page I want it instead returns "Sign In".

Some other possibly relevant info: I've tried several different pages to login from. Currently I'm passing the page I want which then sends scrapy to the login page which looks like this: (Goto -> www.site.com, Site sends scrapy to https://www.site.com/login.aspx?pg=1&view=all&next=http%3a%2f%2fwww.site.com, Goto -> www.site.com, Correct page appears in browser. Use hsx to get title. title = "Sign in". Also I'm not sure if one spider is more appropriate than another. I started with base, currently it's on crawl, didn't notice any differences.

Thank you for any help!

```py
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Response,FormRequest,Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from selenium import webdriver
from ex.items import exItem
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class ex(CrawlSpider):
name = 'ex'
start_urls = ['http://www.site.com']

def get_cookies(self):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(12)
    base_url = "http://www.site.com"
    driver.get(base_url)
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("123")
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("123")
    driver.find_element_by_name("signin").click()
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    return cookies

def parse(self, response,my_cookies=get_cookies):
    return Request(url="http://www.site.com",
        cookies=self.get_cookies(),
        callback=self.login)

def login(self,response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'email': '123', 'password': '123'}, 
        dont_filter=True, callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
    return Request(url="http://www.site.com", dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//title")
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = exItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('//title/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
    driver.close()
```

Comment: I ended up fixing this problem by adapting this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038082/using-scrapy-with-selenium-to-scape-a-rendered-page-updated. However it gave me connection refused errors. To overcome this I deleted the line and lines dependent on                                                                       self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.linkedin.com")